# How to delete elements from the middle of a pointer array using free() or any other method?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, free, calloc

I have created a pointer array using calloc and I want to delete elements starting from the middle of the array.What are the ways in which this can be done?

Comment: Can You use the realloc function?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? perphaps you should just clone the data to a newly allocated memory, and free the old one. Or just use realloc.

Comment: _"I have created a pointer array"_: can you show some lines of relevant code and declarations? It's always easier to see code instead of a code description.

Answer (score 2):

You can only pass to `free` a pointer that was returned from `malloc`, `realloc`, or `calloc`.

If you want to remove a value from the middle of any array (dynamically allocated or otherwise), you need to move each value above it down by one element.  You'll also want to keep track of how many "active" elements the array contains in some way.